# How to build WineLib for Mac OS X 10.6 and link it with XCode project?

Tags: xcode, macos, wine, mac-frameworks, winelib

Please **forgive me** for a stupid lame question, but I can't find even minimal documentation... It seems that only **Wine** is covered.

Should I use the **Wine sources** to build **Winelib**? Is my assumption correct that I can create a **Winelib** framework by importing all **Wine sources** into a project? What middleware / libraries should I link to it in this case?

Please help!